# Model of spread of a rumor

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

From Stewart 7e pg 614 # 9

"One model for the spread of a rumor is that the rate of spread is proportional to the product of the fraction y of the population who have heard th eremor and the fraction who have not hear the rumor.
a) Write a differential equation that is satisfied by y.
b) Solve the differential equation
c) A small town has 1000 inhabitants. At 8 am 80 people have heard a rumor. By noon half the town has heard it. At what will 90 percent of the population have heard the rumor?
"

The wording of this is very ambiguous to me and I can't really make sense of it.

They mention a product, so I know that something is being multiplied and that y is a fraction which belongs to the population who have seen it so I think that "have not" heard is a constant, and that y is a fraction taht represents who have. I tried to set this up and it is the wrong answer. I am not sure what they want from that, the English usage is too ambiguous to make sense of it. The complete lack of punctuation is what really does it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A start:** Let $y=y(t)$ be the fraction who have heard by time $t$. Then the fraction who have not is $1-y$. The rate of change of $y$, we are told, is proportional to the product $y(1-y)$. Our differential equation is therefore
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=ky(1-y).$$
This is a special case of the *logistic equation*, which you know how to solve.

It is convenient to let $t=0$ at $8\colon00$. So $y(0)=\frac{80}{1000}$.  We are told that $y(4)=\frac{1}{2}$.  These two items are enough to tell us everything about the equation, including the constant $k$.  Some algebraic manipulation will be needed.

Now that you have the equation for $y(t)$ in terms of $t$, you can find the $t$ such that $y(t)=0.9$. Note that this $t$ is the time elapsed since $8\colon00$ AM. You will need to give the answer in clock terms.

Comment: I don't understand the use of 1-y to represent of fraction of people who have not heard a rumor.

Comment: Suppose that the fraction of the town that has heard the rumour is $0.35$, that is, $35\%$. Then the fraction that hasn't heard is $65\%$, that is, $0.65$, which is $1-0.35$.

Comment: Was there any logical way to set this up? I never would have thought of that.

Comment: Well, you know it now. Thinking about these problems is a way of gathering experience.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y$ be the fraction of the population that has heard the rumor.  The fraction that has not heard the rumor is then $1-y$.  Our model would then be $y'=ay(1-y)$ where $a$ is the proportionality constant.  Intuitively, the rumor spreads any time somebody who has heard the rumor meets somebody who has not.  For a given meeting, the chance that exactly one has heard the rumor is $2y(1-y)$ and the $2$ can be absorbed in the definition ofFor c), your solution from b) has two unknowns:  the constant of integration and $a$.  You are given two data points, so should be able to determine both constants, then find the time when $y=0.90$ for the final answer.